# Java Socket connection from app to java server

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am setting up an chat app. I have a server, written in java with socket, that connects perfectly to an example code in java. But when I try the exact same code with android studio over the app it doesnt work for some reason.

I have tried to run it with a code outside of the app and it worked. I have got the user permissions on so it can connect to the internet. I have tried to connect to the server on the console and it worked.

The client:

```java
class Client implements Runnable{
    int freePort;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect(){
        System.out.println("Connecting");
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",1336);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            freePort = dataInputStream.readInt();
            System.out.println(freePort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The server:

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DeclarationServer {
    private int numberOfClients = 0;
    DeclarationServer(){
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1336);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "__" + serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println(socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataInputStream.readUTF();
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(1339+numberOfClients);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
                numberOfClients++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

The error message:

```
I/System.out: Connecting
D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{5f45e99 token=android.os.BinderProxy@712539a {com.example.birke.testapp/com.example.birke.testapp.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@712539a
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 1336) from /:: (port 32940): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:137)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
W/System.err:     at com.example.birke.testapp.Client.connect(MainActivity.java:151)
        at com.example.birke.testapp.Client.run(MainActivity.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:118)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:151)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: 10.0.2.2 should be the port you should be connecting to from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this line,

> failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 1336) from /:: (port
>   32940): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

That means, the localhost is refusing the connection most probably, the service/server is not running on the specific port. You would be able to connect to the localhost if the server was running in the same android device.

**Solution**

Pass the IP (private IP if both client and server are in the same network otherwise public IP) of the server instead of `localhost` while initializing `Socket`,

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.XXX.XXX",1336);
```